# Code will not print into cells within the excel worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

We are working with VBA scripts. The assignment is to loop through several sheets within a data set, summarize two different columns and then print that into the columns next to the data that is already there.

When I run the code, nothing seems to happen. No error messages pop up and the debugger doesn't pick up anything either.

**Code**

```
Sub Stock()
    Dim ticker As String
    Dim volume As Double
    volume = 0
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim summary_table_row As Integer
    summary_row_table = 2
    'Set worksheet count
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    'Loop through each year of stock
    For i = 2 To WS_Count
        'Keep track of the years for each stock
        If ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            'Set ticker
            ticker = ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells(i, 1).Value
            'Set volume
            volume = volume + ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells(i, 7).Value
            'Print ticker
            Range("J" & summary_table_row).Value = ticker
            'Print volume
            Range("K" & summary_table_row).Value = volume
            summary_table_row = summary_table_row + 1
            volume = 0
        Else
            volume = volume + ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells(i, 7).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Please point me in a direction to figuring out what is going on?

Comment: you probably intended to loop through sheets, but your code is only looping through cells. you probably meant `Sheets(i).Range`

Comment: You're never setting the ActiveCell or referring to the Worksheets. It's unclear what you actually are attempting

Comment: It'll be the `If` clause - I bet the stuff that you're testing for with the `If` is evaluating to `False` so everything that's supposed to happen underneath it is being ignored. Look more closely at your logic there.